# Nginx redirect to different IP based on port number

Tags: nginx

I have multiple HTTP servers (IoT stuff) connected to a Raspberry Pi with a Nginx instance. I want to proxy the access to those servers through Nginx by using its IP address and multiple ports:

```
192.168.1.100:8080 -> 192.168.2.80
192.168.1.100:8081 -> 192.168.2.81
...
```

I have this configuration in Nginx which works:

```
server {
    listen  8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.80;
        ..... extra config
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to write a separate config entry for every possible address since there can be many and I have to add for each some extra config settings which I don't want to repeat. I know I can add multiple listen ports in the same server configuration, but is there any way to extract the port number and use it to rewrite the proxy_pass address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

An automatic port -> IP address mapping might work like this:

```
map $server_port $upstream {
    "~^80(?<dest>[0-9+])$"   192.168.2.$dest;
}
```

Here a regular expression capture is used to capture the latter part of port number into variable, and then the variable is used in the destination string.

---

I haven't tested this myself, but it should work.

First, you need to define a `map` in the `http` level, which maps port numbers to proxy endpoints:

```
map $server_port $upstream {
    8080     192.168.2.80;
    8081     192.168.2.81;
    8082     192.168.2.82;
    ...
}
```

You might need to add a `default` line to the map.

Then, in the `server` level, you add the following:

```
listen 8080;
listen 8081;
listen 8082;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
}
```

This setup makes a single `server` block listen to multiple ports, and when using the mapped variable as `proxy_pass` destination, it will make nginx send the request to desired destination.

Comment: Thanks! This works well for my purpose. It would be perfect if the map could extract the numbers automatically (i.e. 8080 -> .....2.80), but it's still much better than repeating the server blocks.

Comment: I added a possible automatic mapping rule to the answer.

Comment: After trying different things I realized that the mapping works, but regex in maps is supported only in higher versions of nginx (not the one in the RPi's repositories). It worked after I compiled from the most recent sources. I wish `listen` would take ranges too :) Maybe in a future version.